# How to add variables to several functions in R and run them in the command line

Tags: r, command-line

I have a script that is composed of several functions. A summarised example of my script looks like that

```
>Test.R   
massive.process_1 <- function() {
  seed(123)
  x <- do_something()
  save(x, '/home/Result1.RData')      
}

massive.process_2 <- function() {
  seed(4)
  x <- do_something()
  save(x, '/home/Result2.RData')      
} 

massive.process_1()
massive.process_2()
```

I have to execute this script but instead of 2 _massive.processs_I need to run 100 of them but changing the `seed` value and the name of the data saved in each step. I can do it manually, adding 100 *massive.process* functions but I would like to know if is there any way to put it on a script to avoid typing 100 functions?

Many thanks

My bash file to run it is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Started analysis at: `date`
rfile="Test.R"
Rscript $rfile
echo Finished analysis at: `date`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Dennis's answer...

to change the filename you can use "paste".

```
massive.process <- function(i) {
  seed(i)
  x <- do_something()
  outname = paste("/home/Result", i, ".RData", sep="")
  save(x, outname)
  x
}


for (i in 1:100){
    massive.process(i); 
}
```

or

```
X = lapply(1:100, massive.process)
```

If you use the list approach, to access the ith x, just use X[i]

another way to write the lapply loop is with an anonymous function.  This might make more clear what's going on.

```
X = lapply(1:100, function(i){
  massive.process(i)
})
```

The previous notation is the same, just more compact.

Comment: with your approach @kith_pradhan, each time the function is executed in the loop the memory is erased?, I mean, my real function takes a lot of memory so I want to save `outname` and then run again the second function

Comment: Do you mean the function massive.process updates global variables throughout the iterations?

Comment: No, I mean, Are the objects created inside the function massive.process removed in each iteration? Because these objects take a lot of memory

Comment: My other problem is that once I have generated the 100 .RData files, the x object is the same for each iteraction, is there any way to change the x object to be x.1, x.2, ... thanks @kith pradhan

Comment: @user2380782  step back and diagram your problem.  Then I think you'll realize that, for example, you will know `x.1` vs. `x.2` by the name of your `i.Rdata` files, so when you want to read the data back into `R`, key off the file name.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I know that I can know which x element I looking into just taking in account the `i.RData`, but if I want to combine all the `x` elements in just one object afterwards, it is impossible because each time I read the `i.Rdata` (`load('i.RData)`), the name of the object will be always `x`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the objects inside the function are removed when the function goes out of scope.  You might want to run gc() between iterations to ensure the garbage is collected.

Comment: If you want to save the results from all 100 iterations, it might be better to store them in a list and access them that way.  For example have your function return the "x" rather than saving it, then run the loops with lapply.  results = lapply(1:100,massive.proc).  Then you can access the 33rd x, with results[33]

Comment: @kithpradhan, could you update the answer because I don't see how the seed.value is changed with `apply(1:100, massive.proc)`, sorry if it it is a great inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Why not adding the seed as parameter to the functions?

```
massive.process <- function(seedValue) {...}
```

And it would probably a good idea to implement the loop in R instead of using a shell script.

Comment: the for loop for executing each function could be a good idea, but how change each time the seed value and the name of the saved file? –

Comment: the seed value could be modified with the for loop but I have no clue how change in each loop the name of the saved file